# How to conduct A/B split testing with AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, a-b-testing, revenue

Ok so I have decided to A/B test my AdSense ads. I have run a few tests, but I don't know what conclusion to draw and how to keep track of things. Some specific questions:

1. If I have 2 test units, 1 wins. I test that with a new and so on. How do I find if say the fifth one did better than the first one? How do I keep track of things?
2. Do I let the variables independent of each other, because they certainly are not. In real life, font size can affect CTR even if the colors are different.
3. I can test blue color with red color, and then test Arial font with Georgia, but how do I know which combination is the best? This would result in way too many test units.

I tried Googling a lot, but I could not find answers to these questions.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to do "Multivariate Testing" where you test more than just two variables.

Here is a [guide to walk you through setting up Google Adsense tests using Google Website Optimizer and Google Analytics](http://www.optimizing-adsense.eu/scenarios/scenario-1-optimizing-a-standard-adsense-integration.html).  Here is a summary of the steps involved from the linked article:

1. Create Google Analytics and Website Optimizer accounts if you don't already have them
2. Connect your Google Analytics and AdSense accounts
3. Create an "experiment" in Website Optimizer
4. Install the JavaScript for the experiment on your site
5. Create variations on the test
6. Launch your experiment
7. Stop your experiment